# Why does the gravitational field for certain configurations, at certain points in space, diverge to infinity?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity

I recently came across this [problem](http://webdev.physics.harvard.edu/academics/undergrad/probweek/prob15.pdf), in David Morin's weekly problem set. The solution to which I figured, as explained [here](http://webdev.physics.harvard.edu/academics/undergrad/probweek/sol15.pdf). But I also came across the solution explained in this [report](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1412.5541.pdf). Here the author solves the problem in n dimensions too and concludes that in 2-dimensional space, the object that gives maximum field would a thin circular plate, and not the planar cross-section of the 3D object found to give maximal field before.

I tried to verify this by calculating fields for the 2 different candidates, but I found the field for a uniform circular plate on a point on the circumference diverges to infinity. Same is the case for various objects, like a uniform semicircular plate at the centre. Why does this happen? Why is it that the field does not diverge for a uniform sphere at the surface of the sphere but it does for other objects? Also, will this be practically experienced?

Comment: How thin is the plate? Have you implicitly assumed that it is a plane, which would give it no volume and infinite density?

Comment: It's hard to comment without knowing what calculation you did that resulted in divergences.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/12703/2451

Comment: @CharlesFrancis I did assume that the plate to be of almost zero thickness. But not as the solution for the same question, but a modified one. Say if we were asked to shape a very thin plate without altering its thickness, such that the field on a point in the plane of the plate was to be maximum. That is by keeping its surface mass density the same. Basically a 2-D equivalent for the same question.

Comment: @garyp To find the resultant field contributed by a circular disk of minimal thickness at a point 'P' on the circumference, I used polar coordinates with the point 'P' as the origin and divided the disk into arcs with thickness 'dr', and integrated field contributed by each over the entire disk. This integral did not converge.